# Access Unnamed Value in Ajax Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I'm iterating over an object returned via an Ajax call which is made up of ID and name pairs, looking like:

```
1234: "Lorem",
2345: "Ipsum,
...
```

My loop looks like

```
$( items ).each( function( key, value ) {
    # do something
}
```

Notice that that the IDs aren't keys, they're not sequential. Where I'm getting stuck is that I can't access those values independently. If I use `key` returns the key (of course) not the ID and `value[0]` doesn't work, `value` returns the pair like `1234: "Lorem"`. If my values were named then I could use `value.name` and `value.id` but they aren't.

So my question is, how do I access those unnamed values in my loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let items = {
     1234: "Lorem",
     2345: "Ipsum",
}

$.each(items, function( key, value ) {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For more details, check the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: Magic! Thanks, @ Majed Badawi